# Authorize(Roles = "Admin") always return ACCESS DENIED

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm spending lot time with this thing that appear easy, but can't find solution.

Create a project and working well, login, register, etc. But Authorization not working with roles. Roles are created and setteds:

But always return Access Denied when try to access:

```
public class _ConfigurationsController : Controller
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "AdminApp")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Startup.cs
...

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnection")));

    services.AddDbContext<Scaffolding_AutoGer_Context>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnection")));

    services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
        .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
        .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

}


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

**In debug windows are show this messages:**

```
...Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService:Information: Authorization failed.
...: Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
...: Executing ForbidResult with authentication schemes ().
...Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler:Information: AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was forbidden.
```

**AspNetRoles Table**

[image]

**AspNetUsers Table**

[image]

**AspNetUserRoles Table**

[image]

MVC - Scaffolding project
Individual Accounts Login
.NET Core 2.1
VS 2017

UPDATED:

Login class - autogenerate

[AllowAnonymous]
public class LoginModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly SignInManager _signInManager;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

```
public LoginModel(SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager, ILogger<LoginModel> logger)
{
    _signInManager = signInManager;
    _logger = logger;
}

[BindProperty]
public InputModel Input { get; set; }

public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }

public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

[TempData]
public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

public class InputModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Memorizar?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}

public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ErrorMessage);
    }

    returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

    // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

    ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

    ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Usuário logado .");
            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }
        if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
        {
            return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
        }
        if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("Conta bloqueada!");
            return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Login inválido.");
            return Page();
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return Page();
}
```

}

Comment: Can you add the code you're using for authentication to your question? I assume you're using the templated code, but it helps to verify.

Comment: @TiesonT. Updated Login.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue is related to not having configured policies.
In `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` specify these.

```
 services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            options.AddPolicy("AdminApp",
                policy => policy.RequireClaim("Manager")));
```

More info here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: In this case I need create manually this claims? "Manager", "Superviser"

Comment: Claim and Value are two different things. They are like "Key" and "Value" of a dictionary. In the above example we are looking for claims only. The value in those claims can be anything. So what we are validating here is, that under "AdminApp" policy, you need to have "Manager" and "Supervisor" claims. Please go through the above document. It explains this very well.

Comment: Please ignore "Supervisor" claim. In this example we are looking for "Manager" claim only.

Comment: I asked about database, not need change nothing? In this documentation I not find about it.

Comment: Your database is fine. No need to change anything. You just need to make sure the claim that you want to validate, is present in your Identity. If you do not have a claim called "Manager" (you probably don't) then change the policy to look for most common claims like "name" or "sub". Once you get that working, you can play around with claims.

Comment: Solved. You help me but find complete solution here: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/role-base-authorization-in-asp-net-core-2-1/ I was confunsing claim and role.

Comment: @DiegoVenâncio Technically, since the template defaults to using ClaimsIdentity and ClaimsPrincipal, you're not "wrong" - roles are managed using the ClaimTypes.Role claim

Comment: In my case I have the policy in the startup file but its still saying false access denied even though the user is in the role

Answer (score 0):

add .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
.AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
```

and relogin user